# Smoke coming from behind engine with a stutter at idr

Tags: engine, nissan, overheating, smoke, quest

A couple weeks ago my Nissan Quest overheated blew the radiator cap off. Replace the lower and upper radiator hose, change the thermostat but now there's smoke coming from behind the engine and a resistance in the accelerator.

There seems to be oil leaking from somewhere but we can't figure it out. There is oil in our spark plugs. I check the oil. It looks dirty but it's not a chocolate milk substance, so I don't think we blew a head gasket.

I have no idea what's wrong.

Comment: Welcome to the site. I'm wondering exactly what your question is here? Also, there's more than one way to blow the headgasket without oil getting into the coolant.

Comment: Besides what Paulster2 asked you for, there are a lot of details that would help us understand what happened and is happening. Was the overheating a result of the cap blowing off? Or did the cap blow off because the engine overheated? How long was the engine running in the overheated state (was it shut off immediately)? Was there any evidence of oil before the engine overheated? What does "*resistance in the accelerator*" mean? Is the pedal actually hard to push? Or does the car not want to go when you push the accelerator?

Comment: The overheating caused the radiator cap to blow off